# What is the optimal way to filter rows from a DataTable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, dataset, datarow

I'm looking for the easiest and fastest way to get DataRows from a DataTable.
These DataRows have several columns including one with Integer and I only want the rows with the highest value.

Currently i get this result like this :

```
Dim maxValue = 0
For Each row In mDataTable.Rows
If row.valueCell > maxValue Then
    maxValue = row.valueCell
    End If
Next
Dim mDataTableBis = mDataTable.Clone
For Each row In mDataTable.Select("value = " & valueCell)
    mDataTableBis.ImportRow(row)
Next
```

Original DataTable (for example):

| Rows | letters | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 (wanted) | x | 4 |
| row 2 | y | 2 |
| row 3 (wanted) | z | 4 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [start tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The code you posted is not valid, please show what you tried and where you are facing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer the for-each loop approach, like it seems from the code you posted, use this function:

```
Public Sub ForEachLoop()

    Dim maxValue As Integer

    ' Loop through rows to find max value
    For Each row As DataRow In mDataTable.Rows
        Dim currentRowValue As Integer = row.Field(Of Integer)(numbersColumn)
        If currentRowValue > maxValue Then
            maxValue = currentRowValue
        End If
    Next

    ' Create a List of DataRow
    Dim res As New List(Of DataRow)

    ' Loop through rows again to add to list each row in which numbersColumn field = maxValue
    For Each row As DataRow In mDataTable.Rows
        If row.Field(Of Integer)(numbersColumn) = maxValue Then
            res.Add(row)
        End If
    Next

    ' Create results DataTable copying the List to a new DataTable
    Dim result As DataTable = res.CopyToDataTable()

End Sub
```

If you would like something more concise, you can try with LINQ but this is a more advanced solution, surely not beginner-friendly.

Something like:

```
Public Sub LINQ()

    ' Find the row with highest value in numbersColumn, then get the value from the field
    Dim maxValue As Integer = mDataTable.AsEnumerable().MaxBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)(numbersColumn)).Field(Of Integer)(numbersColumn)

    ' Select all the rows with numbersColumn value = maxValue (this returns an IEnumerable of DataRow)
    Dim resultsRows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = mDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)(numbersColumn) = maxValue)

    ' Create results DataTable copying the IEnumerable to a new DataTable
    Dim result As DataTable = resultsRows.CopyToDataTable()

End Sub
```

You could also use the `DataTable.Select()` method...

```
Public Sub DataTableSelect()

    Dim result As DataTable = mDataTable.Select("numbersColumn = max(numbersColumn)").CopyToDataTable()

End Sub
```

...but this is significally slower than a for each loop:

[image: Benchmark]

As you can see, the for each version is around 3500 times faster than the `Select()` version - that's a big difference!
This test has been executed on a relatively small DataTable with around 10k rows - imagine how big the difference could be in a million-rows-DataTable.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of answers I was looking for.
You helped me a lot, especially with the comparison of execution times by method.
Why the DataTable.Select() method is so slow ?

Comment: @QuentinL Glad my answer helped you! DataTable.Select() has to perform additional tasks compared to LINQ methods or for each loop - it has to parse the query text and probably it has to build an internal index and other overhead code. I'd really wish I could answer this more in detail, but I'm not experienced enough to explain how the Select() method really works internally - hopefully some skilled programmer can add a better explanation about this huge performance difference. BTW, the Select() method is usually considered a bad practice, use it only if you have really no alternatives.

Comment: @QuentinL I forgot to mention (I edited the answer a few seconds ago): my benchmark was executed on a 10k rows DataTable; if you can tell me how many rows has your DataTable, I'll be happy to run again the benchmark.

Comment: @PrivateFranck My table is 10k to 100k rows long, so the tests you ran are in line with the size of my table (quite small). Your explanations on the DataTable.Select() method make sense now.